# Created span in javascript is showing as [object HTMLSpanElement] in webpage

Tags: javascript, dom

I created a span tag in javascript and using .innerHTML i'm trying to append it into another tag. but in webpage it is showing as [object HTMLSpanElement].

```js
var text = "Accessor Properties Example";
var enteredText = 'Prop';
var data = text.split(enteredText);
var pTag = document.getElementById('ab');
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.setAttribute('class','highlight');
newSpan.innerHTML=enteredText;
console.log(newSpan)
var plainText = data[0]+newSpan+data[1];
pTag.innerHTML = plainText;
```

```css
.highlight {color:#1a0dab;font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<p id="ab"></p>
```

Comment: Change this 
var plainText = data[0]+newSpan+data[1]; 
to
var plainText = data[0]+newSpan.innerText+data[1];

Comment: @MuraliMopuru - nope. Doing so removes the span tag and replaces it with its contents. This means that the text `Prop` is not shown in blue. ;)

Comment: Your variable name 'plainText ' giving wrong msg. then use 'newSpan.innerHTML'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to insert an object reference into a string. You can get the HTML that represents the span and add the 3 pieces of information together before setting the innerHTML of your target.

```js
var text = "Accessor Properties Example";
var enteredText = 'Prop';
var data = text.split(enteredText);
var pTag = document.getElementById('ab');
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.setAttribute('class','highlight');
newSpan.innerHTML=enteredText;
console.log(newSpan)
var plainText = data[0]+ newSpan.outerHTML +data[1];  // <- Change made here
pTag.innerHTML = plainText;
```

```css
.highlight {color:#1a0dab;font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<p id="ab"></p>
```

Comment: Note `innerHTML` will parse the text as HTML. Given the variable is named `plainText`, I think this was not desired.

Comment: Given that it is to contain a span which is used for styling, I'd argue that while your method is _my_ preferred method, this answer I've provided achieves the desired result in the attempted manner. My 5c says the variable is deceptively named.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are concatenating strings with a DOM element, which is coerced into a string too.

Instead, you should use `appendChild`:

```
pTag.innerHTML = ''; // Remove existing contents
pTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0]));
pTag.appendChild(newSpan);
pTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[1]));
```

```js
var text = "Accessor Properties Example",
    enteredText = 'Prop',
    data = text.split(enteredText),
    pTag = document.getElementById('ab'),
    newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.className = 'highlight';
newSpan.textContent = enteredText;
pTag.innerHTML = '';
pTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0]));
pTag.appendChild(newSpan);
pTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[1]));
```

```css
.highlight {color:#1a0dab;font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<p id="ab"></p>
```